# How to select identically names div elements when writing cypress tests

Tags: html, dom, bdd, e2e-testing, cypress

I'm using cypress to create E2E test for our new application.

The application has a menu that contains buttons to display different data on a map screen.  All of these buttons have the same div name, which I can differentiate between by entering the text name of the button:

```js
cy.get('div.sb-item-body').contains('Historical Land Uses').click()
cy.get('div.sb-item-body').contains('Potentially Contaminative Industrial Uses (Past Land Use)').click()
cy.get('div.sb-item-body').contains('Potentially Infilled Land (Water)').click()
```

There is a further complication where two of the buttons have the same title (Landfill and Waste) as that dataset is in two different sections.  So when I attempt to access the second -

```js
cy.get('div.sb-item-body').contains('Landfill and Waste').click()
```

It is trying to select the first button with that name, and it's failing as that button has been collapsed and is no longer selectable.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am guessing you don't have access to the developers to change the code so there is some sort of id that make them unique. I also believe there is a way to select an element at a certain element.If I find it I will post an answer..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the [.eq()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/eq.html#Syntax) syntax.

You can use this when the selector returns multiple elements, e.g

```js
cy.get('div.sb-item-body').contains('Landfill and Waste').eq(0).click()
cy.get('div.sb-item-body').contains('Landfill and Waste').eq(1).click()
```

I'm not sure if the 'collapsed' first button might interfere with it.

A more long-winded way is to use `.then()` to process the array of returned values, e.g

```js
cy.get('div.sb-item-body').contains('Landfill and Waste').then(els => {
  const buttons = [...els];
  cy.wrap(buttons[0]).click()
  expect(..).to...
  cy.wrap(buttons[1]).click()
  expect(..).to...
})
```

The spread operator converts the wrapped elements into an array you can work with, and `cy.wrap()` re-wraps the selected item making it clickable.